# Beanshell Pattern Matcher Regex

Tags: java, json, regex, beanshell

I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "": "",
        "substituted_restday": "2020-02-01",
        "original_restday": "2020-02-08",
        "id": "15d13f70-c0a852c0-3a925f13-6dca1982",
        "_UNIQUEKEY_": "15d1592a-c0a852c0-3a925f13b7c65023",
        "parentId": ""
    }, 
    {
        "": "",
        "substituted_restday": "2020-02-03",
        "original_restday": "2020-02-09",
        "id": "15d14d55-c0a852c0-3a925f13-727b70af",
        "_UNIQUEKEY_": "15d1592a-c0a852c0-3a925f13-3711a584",
        "parentId": ""
    }
]
```

I want to extract the "date" from "substituted_restday", which is 2020-02-01 and 2020-02-03.

I have the following code, but the result is not good:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\"substituted_restday\":\")[0-9-]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(JSON);
System.out.println(matcher.find());                     
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher);
    System.out.println("group count:" + matcher.groupCount());
    for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ":" + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

I can see the "matcher.find()" is true. But matcher.group has no value. Please help.

Comment: In the JSON-String there is after substituted_restday a space and the date has quotes left and right. I miss them in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the matched pattern and then access `group(1)`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"substituted_restday\": \"([0-9-]+)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(JSON);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
2020-02-01
2020-02-03
```

If you access `group(0)` the output is:

```
 "substituted_restday": "2020-02-01"
 "substituted_restday": "2020-02-03"
```

> The groups are identified by the brackets
>
> `group(0)`: `("\"substituted_restday\": \"([0-9-]+)\"")`
>
> `group(1)`: `([0-9-]+)`